# How to change the default delimiter in PostgreSQL 9.1.9 using SET?

Tags: postgresql-9.1

From within a bash script I tried to use a replace and a detection on a field containing a pipe like:

```
IF position ('|' in var) IS NOT NULL THEN ...

...REPLACE(field, '|', '#')
```

The data itself was loaded into the DB using the COPY statement e.g.

```
COPY records FROM '$datasource' WITH DELIMITER AS ',' CSV HEADER NULL as '';
```

I am using psql (9.1.9) and the default field separator is pipe:

```
#> \f
#> Field separator is "|".
```

Ideally I would like to SET the default limiter in a CREATE OR REPLACE function at runtime like:

```
...
END; \$\$ LANGUAGE plpgsql SET config_param TO '#';
```

OR as a seperate statement just like
    SET config_param TO '#';

I searched the documentation and internet for the right name of the config parameter without luck. Any help appreciated.

Comment: Do you want to change the delimiter when runing DDL statements, the delimiter used when displaying data or the column delimiter when importing data via COPY?

Comment: The COPY statement which loads the data into proper fields should not be touched because it is a comma separated file. But for the given example fields can contain pipe-delimiters. These strings are shown correctly in the fields, but working on them with replace or to detect the pipe using POSITION does not work. So I would like to use SET in my function at least or call set from within a bash script. Example:

    function afunction {
    <<EOF
    SET config_param TO '#';
    BEGIN;
    ....
    
    COMMIT;
    EOF
    }

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This:

```
`IF position ('|' in var) IS NOT NULL`
```

is assuming that the result of `position('|' in 'nopipes')` is `NULL`. It is not, it's zero. `position` returns null only on null input.

```
regress=> select position('|' in 'abc|def|ghi');
 position 
----------
        4
(1 row)

regress=> select position('|' in 'abcdefghi');
 position 
----------
        0
(1 row)

regress=> select position('|' in null);
 position 
----------

(1 row)
```

... so if you instead wrote:

```
IF position ('|' in var) <> 0
```

it should work fine.

The field separator `\f` in `psql` is irrelevant to this. It's only used to control *how `psql` displays result sets*. The server and functions on the server cannot see or be affected by this value. `\f` is just shorthand for `\pset fieldsep`, it's a psql-local control to choose the field separator for `unaligned` output:

```
regress=> \pset format unaligned
Output format is unaligned.
regress=> SELECT 1,2,3;
?column?|?column?|?column?
1|2|3
(1 row)
regress=> \pset fieldsep #
Field separator is "#".
regress=> SELECT 1,2,3;
?column?#?column?#?column?
1#2#3
(1 row)
```

Comment: Thank you, Craig. Yes indeed:
    position('|' in 'nopipes')
should return zero.

For the sake of completeness:
    show all;

lists all config parameters and there is no config parameter to change the default limiter.