# See entire string from a lengthy text field in pgAdmin?

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin

Using [pgAdmin](http://pgadmin.org), how can I see the entire string value for a row when the value is very long?

For example, the value may be [comma-separated values (CSV)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values) content with hundreds or thousands of characters. Furthermore, the value may contain newline characters.

When doing queries in pgAdmin’s SQL tool, the results pane only shows a few dozen characters, and then suppresses the display of any more. Is there some way to see all of the text value?

Any way to export the results of a query to a text file or a text window perhaps?

Comment: Why do you want to _see_ such a big something?  Is it really there for human consumption?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31828182/incomplete-information-from-query-on-pg-views

Comment: http://dave.webdev.pgadmin.org/support/faq.php#ColTrunc

Comment: you can also copy and paste the output cell to say notepad to view it. it's a PITA I agree

Comment: @NeilMcGuigan Nope, copy-paste of the cell does not work. You get a chunk, but the rest of the text is truncated, replaced by a pseudo-ellipsis. For example, the tail look like this: `"11.21","8,11 (...)"`

Answer (score 9):

- Open pgAdminIII,
- Select your database,
- Use the Magnifying Glass button, i.e. "Execute arbitrary SQL queries"
- Instead of running your query using the green triangle  "Execute Query", choose
  the button two to the right of that - i.e. "Execute Query, write result to file".
- Choose your destination, then you can view arbitrary length text in your chosen file destination.
- You can also use psql which will show text, but will scroll if that's any use. Also, there would be the possibility of scripting your query output using different delimiters.

Comment: Thanks, that does work. Unfortunately, that feature seems to **support only exporting as CSV**. My stored value is already CSV text. That results in the quotes and such being doubled so as to escape them. So I cannot actually see my stored CSV in its original condition.

Comment: Can't you use pipe (|) as a separator and then use sed (or vi or whatever) to remove the pipes - you could script it so you wouldn't have to manually intervene.

Comment: Check [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8514503/convert-pipe-delimited-csv-to-tab-delimited-using-batch-script) - a couple of methods to deal with this problem. And [this](http://dba.stackexchange.com/a/45969/34007) might also be of interest. Ringer is on the PostgreSQL team and also contributes here.

Answer (score 1):

In PgAdmin, edit the value of Max. characters per column by following these steps :

File > Options > Query Editor > Max. characters per column

In some case you could find Query Tool instead of Query Editor.

Comment: What is the setting called in PGADMIN4?